# Parse a long text string of the ini file stored in a cell of the SQL Server table

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Help me parse a long text string of the ini file stored in a cell of the SQL Server table.

I have a table with columns `id, rawINI`.

In the `rawINI` column, the structure of the INI file is as follows:

```
[BlockName1]
Key1=value
Key2=value1,value2,value3
Key3=
[BlockName1]
Key1=value
Key2=value1,value2,value3
Key3=
```

It is necessary to convert this text into the form of a new table, for example (maybe you can recommend another way?):

```
Block,Key,Value
--------------------------------------
BlockName1,Key1,value
BlockName1,Key2,value1,value2,value3
BlockName1,Key3
BlockName2,Key1,value
BlockName2,Key2,value1,value2,value3
BlockName2,Key3
```

I'm not familiar with T-SQL and I don't even know where to start solving this problem. How can this be solved? What features can help?

Comment: T-SQL isn't your friend here. Using *something else* to parse the data and convert it into a dataset. Though you expected results don't look ideal either; it looks like you're after a variable number of columns which you can't do (if you want to store to in SQL Server, completely normalise the data)

Comment: Also tables don't have "cells", that is something you'll find in a spreadsheet. Tables have rows and columns, and each column in a row has a value. You don't store the value in a "cell" you store it in a column in a row.

Comment: .ini files went out of fashion when .NET Framework 1.0 got introduced with XML-based .config files back in 2002. Do you have something that actually still uses .ini files?

Comment: Sometimes there are old programs and strict requirements and the inability to change the architecture of data obtaining ...

Comment: Someone raise the rating of the question to zero, because I don't want to delete it, there is no such solution in Google :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As an example :

```
DECLARE @TEXT VARCHAR(max) = 
'[BlockName1]
Key1=value
Key2=value1,value2,value3
Key3=
[BlockName2]
Key1=value
Key2=value1,value2,value3
Key3=';

WITH 
T AS
(
SELECT CONCAT('[', value) AS VAL, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY value) AS ORD
FROM STRING_SPLIT(@TEXT, '[')
WHERE value <> ''
),
S AS
(
SELECT ORD, LEFT(VAL, CHARINDEX(']', VAL)) AS BLOC, 
       SUBSTRING(VAL, CHARINDEX(']', VAL) + 3 , LEN(VAL) - CHARINDEX(']', VAL)) AS K
FROM   T
)
SELECT ORD, BLOC, value AS CLE
FROM   S
       CROSS APPLY STRING_SPLIT(K, CHAR(10))
WHERE  value <> ''
```

That results :

```
ORD                  BLOC                   CLE
-------------------- ---------------------- ---------------------------
1                    [BlockName1]           Key1=value
1                    [BlockName1]           Key2=value1,value2,value3
1                    [BlockName1]           Key3=
2                    [BlockName2]           Key1=value
2                    [BlockName2]           Key2=value1,value2,value3
2                    [BlockName2]           Key3=
```

Thenyou can apply the same principe of STRING SPLIT (on coma) another time to extract values of keys

Comment: You are my savior! It remains for me to understand how it works :)

Answer (score 0):

Thank you so much for @SQLPro great help! The final solution to my problem:

```
WITH 
[BLOCKS] AS
(
SELECT CONCAT('[', value) AS [RAW]
FROM STRING_SPLIT(@rawINI, '[')
WHERE value <> ''
),
[PAIRS] AS
(
SELECT LEFT([RAW], CHARINDEX(']', [RAW])) AS [BLOCK], 
        SUBSTRING([RAW], CHARINDEX(']', [RAW]) + 3 , LEN([RAW]) - CHARINDEX(']', [RAW])) AS [PAIR]
FROM   [BLOCKS]
)

SELECT LTRIM(RTRIM([BLOCK])) AS [BLOCK],
        LTRIM(RTRIM(REPLACE(LEFT([KeyVal], CHARINDEX('=',[KeyVal])),'=',''))) AS [KEY],
        LTRIM(RTRIM(REPLACE(SUBSTRING([KeyVal], CHARINDEX('=',[KeyVal]), LEN([KeyVal]) - CHARINDEX('=', [KeyVal])),'=',''))) AS [VAL]
    FROM
    (
    SELECT [BLOCK], value AS [KeyVal]
    FROM  [PAIRS]
        CROSS APPLY STRING_SPLIT([PAIR], CHAR(10)) 
    WHERE  value <> ''
    ) AS RAWTABLE
WHERE  [KeyVal] <> ''
```

p.s. i need to learn more about CROSS APPLY ...